# Cannot access 'home/username/Maildir':

Tags: server, permissions, email, postfix, webserver

I just started learning ubuntu 20.04 server and trying to set up mail system (To use Thunderbird) I am using online tutorial, to set up Postfix.
Here is the link which I following tutorial
[enter link description here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-20-04)

At this point I get stuck.Maildir folder not created automatically

```
echo 'export MAIL=~/Maildir' | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/mail.sh


ls -R ~/Maildir
```

ls: cannot access 'home/username/Maildir': no such file or directory

Here is my main.cf

```
myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myorigin = /etc/mailname
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
```

I tried everything similar fixing the issue but nothing worked for me. Am I need to add my VPS IP address to mynetworks line ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include more context and details. `ls` only lists files. It doesn't do anything else. What exactly are you trying to do?  If you are following a tutorial, you need to link to it and tell us where exactly you are stuck.  Also, it's clear that the output of your `ls` command is not copy-pasted accurately. That output would not have come from that command. In your edit please make sure that all commands and output are copy/pasted verbatim. Even something as small as a `/` out of place will have a drastically different result.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 webserver  What is this never heard of it?

Comment: @David My fault , I edited again as  a server.